# Rails i18n ActiveRecord backed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, rails-i18n

I want to store web site translations in ActiveRecord, because it easy to edit in admin area.

I found only one solution: 
https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record

But it is completable with 3rd version of rails and last commit was one year ago. I have rails4 application.

Is it any alternative activerecord backends for i18n?

Comment: It should still work with Rails 4, have you tried it?

Comment: yes, I tried, but I have protected_attributes gem, which causes error at i18n-active_record gem